# Integration $\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}{\frac{a^{z+1}}{z+1}}\operatorname d\!z$

Tags: complex-analysis

So, I'm trying to evaluate the integral below, and I'm having a very difficult time even getting started.

$$\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}{\frac{a^{z+1}}{z+1}}dz$$
where a is a real number, and I am to consider the cases for which a > 1 and 0 < a < 1.

Although I'm not sure where to start, I have a feeling that I'm going to have to make some kind of branch cut and do contour integration.  Also, perhaps this helps to simplify somehow?  Should I try to employ analytic continuation somehow?

$$a^{z+1}=e^{(z+1)\log{|a|}}$$

Any insight and a starting path would be much appreciated; I have been struggling with this guy for awhile.

Comment: Hint: There is a pole at $z = -1$. Can you throw a semicircle around it and use Cauchy's Residue Theorem?

Comment: @RobertK Yes, thank you; I'm now trying to take a contour integral from -iR to iR and with an arc connecting both on the left half-plane. Though, I'm now having trouble evaluating the integral over that arc =/.

Comment: Depending on whether $0 < a < 1$ or $a > 1$, you need to take the semicircle in one or the other half-plane. You want $\lvert a^{z+1}\rvert$ to decay when you're far away from the imaginary axis.

Comment: @DanielFischer very interesting.  Why would the choice of the half-plane affect that?  Is it due to the limits of integration for the arc integral?

Comment: It's the other way round. It blows up in one half-plane, and decays in the other. You then choose the half-plane you put the semicircle in accordingly.

Comment: @DanielFischer hmmmm, I can't really see why that would be the case.  Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral

$$\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty} \frac{a^{z+1}}{z+1}\,dz$$

exists - as an improper Riemann integral - only for $0 < a < 1$ and $a > 1$, and only if we take the branch of $a^{z+1}$ that is real-valued on $\mathbb{R}$. The integrand is an entire meromorphic function with a simple pole in $-1$ and no other pole, and for the numerator we find

$$\lvert a^{z+1}\rvert = e^{(\operatorname{Re} z + 1)\log a},$$

so for $0 < a < 1$, when $\log a < 0$, it decays exponentially for $\operatorname{Re} z \to +\infty$ and grows exponentially for $\operatorname{Re} z\to -\infty$, while for $a > 1$ ($\log a > 0$) it grows for $\operatorname{Re} z \to +\infty$ and decays for $\operatorname{Re} z \to -\infty$.

For $0 < a < 1$, we consider the contour $C_R$ consisting of the interval $[-iR,iR]$ on the imaginary axis, and the semicircle $\gamma_R(t) = R\cdot e^{i(\pi/2-t)},\; 0 \leqslant t \leqslant\pi$ in the right half plane. By Jordan's lemma,

$$\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{\gamma_R} \frac{a^{z+1}}{z+1}\,dz \to 0$$

then, and by Cauchy's integral theorem, since the integrand is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of the closed right half-plane,

$$\int_{C_R} \frac{a^{z+1}}{z+1}\,dz = 0,$$

whence in this case

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty} \frac{a^{z+1}}{z+1}\,dz
&= \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{-iR}^{iR}\frac{a^{z+1}}{z+1}\,dz\\
&= -\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{\gamma_R}\frac{a^{z+1}}{z+1}\,dz\\
&= 0.
\end{align}$$

For $a > 1$, to have the integral over the auxiliary part of the closed contour tend to $0$, we need to choose the closing semicircle in the left half plane, and integrate over the contour $\tilde{C}_R$ consisting of the interval $[-iR,iR]$ on the imaginary axis and the semicircle $\tilde{\gamma}_R = R\cdot e^{i(\pi/2+t)},\; 0 \leqslant t \leqslant \pi$. Again by Jordan's lemma,

$$\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{\tilde{\gamma}_R} \frac{a^{z+1}}{z+1}\,dz \to 0,$$

and by Cauchy's integral formula, we have

$$\int_{\tilde{C}_R} \frac{a^{z+1}}{z+1}\,dz = 2\pi i a^{(-1)+1} = 2\pi i,$$

hence

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty} \frac{a^{z+1}}{z+1}\,dz
&= \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{-iR}^{iR} \frac{a^{z+1}}{z+1}\,dz\\
&= \lim_{R\to\infty} \left(2\pi i - \int_{\tilde{\gamma}_R}\frac{a^{z+1}}{z+1}\,dz\right)\\
&= 2\pi i - \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{\tilde{\gamma}_R}\frac{a^{z+1}}{z+1}\,dz\\
&= 2\pi i.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Wow, that was a very detailed explanation; thank you!  Though, I'm a bit skeptical about your reference to Jordan's Lemma.  For that to work, we usually need something of the form $g(z)e^{iaz}$, but we have something of the form $e^{az}$.  So, we won't end up with $|e^{-aR\sin(\theta)}|$ under the integral (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma).  Is there any other way to prove that it vanishes? I tend to struggle with cases in which Jordan's Lemma does not apply.

Comment: The $e^{ibz}$ is for when the semicircle is in the upper or lower half-plane, here we rotate by $\pi/2$, so we need (and have) $e^{bz}$ instead of $e^{ibz}$. If you rotate the entire shemozzle and write $z = iw$, you get $$i\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{a^{iw+1}}{iw+1}\,dw.$$ That may look a little more familiar.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh, that's why your contour over the arc looked so odd  to me; you're doing that to apply Jordan's theorem; that's brilliant!  Such a cool, clever little trick; thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
With $\ds{\quad z \equiv it\quad\imp\quad t = -\ic z}$:
\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\large\int_{-\ic\infty}^{\ic\infty}{{a^{z + 1} \over z + 1}}\,\dd z}&=
a\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{{a^{\ic t} \over \ic t + 1}}\,\pars{\ic\,\dd t}
=a\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{{a^{\ic t} \over t -\ic }}\,\dd t
=a\bracks{2\pi\ic\, a^{\ic\pars{\ic}}} =\color{#00f}{\large 2\pi\ic}
\end{align}

> In the complex plane, $\ds{t = \Re\pars{t} + \Im\pars{t}\ic}$. The factor
>   $\ds{a^{\ic t}}$ becomes $\ds{a^{\Re\pars{t}\ic}a^{-\Im\pars{t}}}$. Then, the integral is 'closed' in a semi-circle in the upper complex plane such that the factor
>   $\ds{a^{-\Im\pars{t}}}$, when $\ds{a > 0}$, ensures the vanishing of the integration along the semi-circle upper arc when $\ds{\Im\pars{t} \to \infty}$.